# Maven import dependencies with user defines classifier tags

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I try to import a dependency in POM in the following way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.test.maven-presets</groupId>
    <artifactId>caffe</artifactId>
    <version>preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <classifier>pojos</classifier>
</dependency>
```

There are 4 jar files: 1) caffe-preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar 2) caffe-preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar 3) caffe-preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar and 4) caffe-preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-pojos.jar.

My requirement is only I have to use caffe-preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT-pojos.jar. But even though I use the classifier tag, I am still fetching the classes that are under caffe-preset-1.3.3-SNAPSHOT.jar. How can I only use the classes that are under the  tag?

Like I have only the POJOs under 4th Jar which is used as a dependency in another project.

I can add these POJO classes in another project and create a Jar out of it separately and can use in other projects, but our technical team management is not agreeing to create New Project, as it requires different approvals and has to Justify to each of them clearly.

Could anyone please help me to get through the requirement? Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the classes from the main project, but of course, you get the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Fabian for the response. But what i see is i am getting the classes as well as dependencies. Meaning i am able to access the Methods of the Main class and import them succesfully. The main reason we are segregating is that, if we use the main jar, the classes are getting duplicated in another project. Hence we have requirement only to use the Pojos seperatly instead of full Jar. Any way to do that?

Comment: You probably get the classes in some other way. Your approach should work.

Comment: Yeah. Seems to be working, but whether we use the classifier tag or not we can use all of the classess, which is again violating the requirement we are in.

Comment: I think you are mistaken. When you use the classifier, you _don't_ get the other classes. You probably just think you get the other classes, but in reality, they come from somewhere else or your IDE tricks you.